# Database entry multiple records

Tags: php, html

I have a table of inactive users displayed in a table from a mysqli database. I have then created a new row for each user and a cell for each row containing a dropmenu with 3 options - admin , delete user, activate user.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, firstname, lastname, registerdate FROM users WHERE level < 1");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_GET['username'], $_GET['firstname'], $_GET['lastname'], $_GET['registerdate']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $firstname, $lastname, $registerdate);
?>


<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="7"><h1>Inactive Users</h1></th>
<tr>
<td><h2>Username</h2></td>
<td><h2>Firstname</h2></td>
<td><h2>Lastname</h2></td>
<td><h2>Date Registered</h2></td>
<td><h2>Days Inactive</h2></td>
<td><h2>Activate</h2></td>
<td><h2>Submit</h2></td>

<?php 

while ($stmt->fetch()){

$today = new DateTime("now");  
$registered = new DateTime($registerdate);  
$dayspassed = date_diff($registered, $today);

echo '<tr class="'.$username.'">
    <td>'.$username.'</td>
    <td>'.$firstname.'</td>
    <td>'.$lastname.'</td>
    <td>'.$registered->format("d-m-y").'</td>
    <td>'.$dayspassed->format("%a days").'</td>
    <td>
        <select name="'.$username.'" id="'.$username.'">
        <option selected>Select Action</option>
        <option value="activate">Activate User</option>
        <option value="delete">Delete User</option>
        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="'submit'" value="Confirm" />
    </td>';
}


$stmt->close();
?>
</table>
```

I'm trying to write some basic code that will be something like `foreach` dropmenu with the value "activate" insert user into table activated. Each select menu has the name of `$username` collected from the db table. So far i have something like this.

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

{

```
$activate = $_POST["activate"];
$delete = $_POST["delete"];
$admin = $_POST["admin"];

foreach ($username == $_POST["activate"]{
```

Comment: Why not just do an ajax update for each time a dropdown is changed?

Comment: It was so hard for me to understand what you want . Can you be more specific ?

Comment: When submit is pressed the option of the select menu will define the outcome. If i want to apply admin to 3 users when i assign them admin in the select menu and click submit i want them to be added to the admin sql table. I don't understand AJAX

Comment: Ajax is a lot easier than it may seem at first, I promise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when handle $var equals $_POST, you need to check if $_POST is set, otherwise you'll get an error.

```
if(isset($_POST['activate'])) $activate = $_POST['activate'];
```

ok, then, if you select 4 users for example, if you want to handle it, you can use Ajax. with js turn off the default action on submit button, then take all ids for activate, all ids for delete and all ids for anything that you want and concat on an array like array['action_type']['user_id'];

then, you just send it by $_POST to another php to handle.

For better example explanation, you can get:

```
array['activate']['1'];
array['activate']['2'];
array['delete']['3'];
array['activate']['4'];
```

Or you can get

```
array['activate']['1,2,4'];
array['delete']['3'];
```

then you can activate users 1, 2 and 3, and delete user 4 in a loop (use what you like. while, do-while, for, foreach...)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Php for select:

```
<select name="'.$username.'" onchange="updateUser(this)" id="'.$username.'">
```

Then javascript (with jQuery):

```
function updateUser(param) {
    var username = $(param).attr('id');
    var action = $(param).val();
    var phpDataPrepare = [username, action];
    var phpData = JSON.stringify(phpDataPrepare);
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "?action=update_user"; ?>',
        data: phpData,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            //data = response
            //put any javascript here as a success function if needed.
        }
    });
}
```

Then just write the PHP to receive this information (near the top of the same page)

To get your information:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']){
    if($_GET['action'] == 'update_user'){
        $info = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        $username = $info[0];
        $action = $info[1];
        //Do what needs to be done
        exit();
    }
}
```